# meteor installation failed - goes only up to 45%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, meteor

I try to install Meteor on my Ubuntu14 (64 bits). My installation goes up to 45% and can not go more. Do you know the reason of that? I have curl installed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To get a good answer, a specific error or detailed log is probably necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it with root privileges, I had the same issue when first installed Meteor, if this will help simply add privileges to this directory with command

```
sudo chown -R #USER /usr/local (or some other directory)
```

I use it on Linux Mint, but Ubuntu is basically the same so it should be fine

Comment: This should not be necessary as the install script asks for root permission to write to that directory. I've installed on mint and ubuntu without needing to `chown /usr/local`. Besides, I'm not sure changing ownership of `/usr/local/sbin` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am using aswell meteor on Linux Mint, I simply installed meteor on my home folder, I found the latest update took a little longer than the previous release at it seems it checking more things I thought it was stalled aswell but waited and it just finally keep going.

Have you tried the classic stopped and restart the install ?